# How to get back in arch-chroot after ssh lost connection

Tags: installation, arch-linux

I was in an `arch-chroot /mnt` installing Arch following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3-OMUQTf_k&t=363s) and I close my terminal (connected with ssh to the machine) by mistake.

How to get back in the chrooted env ?

If I run again the command `arch-chroot /mnt` I get :

```
root@archiso / # arch-chroot /mnt          
mount: /mnt/sys: sys already mounted on /sys.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
==> ERROR: failed to setup chroot /mnt
```

I asked my self if `cd /mnt/sys` is enough ? I'm not familiar with `chroot`, specialy `arch-chroot` and I don' want to make a mistake and have to redo everything.

Sorry for this noob's question, the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chroot) on chroot was not clear to me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way, not very elegent but efficient :

Unmount the partition where there is the chroot, mount it again then chroot again. The commands for me where :

```
umount -a
mount /dev/sda2/ /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
arch-chroot /mnt
```